# How to select the count of total active listings week by week?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get the count from a table of active apartment listings week by week. The table looks like this (except much longer):

```
id      created_at          delisted_at
2318867 2014-11-12 18:57:44 Null
2329665 2014-11-14 4:36:32  Null
1431098 2014-07-25 5:45:03  Null
1930123 2014-09-28 10:10:46 2014-09-28 10:10:45
2490774 2014-12-05 0:08:47  Null
```

To get an active listings for a single week, you have to check that `created_at <= end_of_week` and `delisted_at > end_of_week`.

The results table would like like a longer version of:

```
Week        Number of Active Listings
5/1/2016    3024
5/8/2016    11234
5/15/2016   11234
```

I would also like to produce another results table month by month as opposed to week by week.

How do I write a query to achieve this behavior?

Comment: You'll probably need a calendar table to hold your end-of-week dates; you will then join the two.

Comment: @mustaccio just curious how did you format the tables like that in your edit?

Comment: A paragraph indented by 4 spaces is treated as code and printed using monospace font. There's a little question mark icon at the top of the edit window, click it next time you edit a question (or answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for month.  First generate a list of months using `generate_series()`.  The rest is just joins and aggregations:

```
select g.mon_start, g.mon_end, count(a.id) as numActives
from (select g.mon_start, g.mon_start + interval '1 month' as mon_end
      from generate_series('2016-01-01'::timestamp, '2016-06-01'::timestamp, interval '1 month'
                          ) g(mon_start)
     ) g left join
     actives a
     on a.created_at < g.mon_end and
        (a.delisted_at >= mon_end or a.delisted_at is null)
group by g.mon_start, g.mon_end
order by g.mon_start, g.mon_end;
```

A similar idea works for weeks as well.

Comment: I got Error : ERROR:  function generate_series(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 4:       from generate_series('2016-01-01'::timestamp, '2016-06...
                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.